# How to remove dead items from the Startup tab in Task Manager?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

I have a couple of programs in the Startup tab, that after being uninstalled remained there.

In this picture you can see Switcher, which used to launch on startup, remains in the tab after being uninstalled.

[image: Switcher remains in the Startup tab after being uninstalled]
*Open file location is greyed out*

How can I clean up my Startup tab, and get rid of these items?

Comment: How exactly did you uninstall it?

Comment: @techie007 I uninstalled Switcher the usual way, from Programs and Features (Add/Removes Programs). I'm really not sure what the other one was, it's just called "Program". I think it was a console program that I simply deleted.

Comment: Have you rebooted since you uninstalled it?

Comment: @techie007 Yes. I also made sure it wasn't in `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. I'm almost certain the other one was a console program ([TouchMousePlus](http://touchmouseplus.codeplex.com/)) that I simply deleted. I never got used to it showing up as "ConsoleApplication1.exe" so I recompiled as it appears in the pic above.

Comment: Anything in `%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`?

Comment: @techie007 just `desktop.ini`

Comment: To the person who recommended autoruns: [your answer worked](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IXAFr.png)! My Startup tab is now nice and clean. I found a bunch of other junk too. Maybe your answer got lost in the migration back to New York, or maybe you deleted it, but since it's a good answer can you rewrite it? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on an answer that got deleted, I wound up installing [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and removed the items from within the program.

[image: Autoruns]

Alternatively, I could have deleted them from the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` branch using [RegEdit](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tools_regeditors.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: user Vulpes Nox commented "this (RegEdit) works best, just dont delete anything but what you are absolutely sure is related to the start up "ghost"

Answer (score 8):

- Startup programs for current user:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

- Startup programs for currently logged on users (also applicable to current user):

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Where `S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX` is the SID of the logged on user.

- Startup programs ran by System account (for all users):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

- 32-bit Startup programs on 64-bit system ran by System account (for all users):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Answer (score 5):

http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/

You can remove the entries using Ccleaner by going to Tools->StartUp-> then you can ENABLE/DISABLE/DELETE any entry

Comment: This does seem to be the perfect solution.  CCleaner would appear to be a serious and safe product; for Mac users like me coming to grips with Windows, CCleaner appears to be OK to use, popular, and won't further mess your system.  I'm surprised there are not more answers and comments on this question.  It's so hard to erase stuff from computers sometimes! Thanks GeMavio, good one

Answer (score 2):

Task Manager gets this list usually from sys-reg, but it may not always be safe to delete all reg keys related to this dead item.
This fix shows how to detect the file origins and how to safely remove them forever, worked with me Windows 10 Pro ..
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/task-manager-unknown-program-startup-entry-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the registry here did worked for me : HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Though not every dead program moved from the tab, then I tried Ccleaner "Tools->StartUp-> then you can ENABLE/DISABLE/DELETE any entry" and it did worked perfectly.