# How do I remove an unknown program from Startup tab of the Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, task-manager

I have an entry that simply says "Program" with no file location or details about what made this entry into my Startup items in Task Manager. I had followed the advice in another superuser question about removing entries from this, but to no avail. After looking at all the registry paths mentioned in [548832](https://superuser.com/questions/548832/how-to-remove-dead-items-from-the-startup-tab-in-task-manager) I was unable to find any keys that could correspond to this blank program. However I was able to find the other Startup entries in those registry locations. I do not have the ability to install a registry cleaner so any fix must be made manually. I am running Windows 10 Version    10.0.19043 Build 19043

[Task Manager on the Startup Tab showing an entry named Program, and the context menu for it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgeUi.png)

Comment: does Autoruns show you anything? there are like 26 ways to autostart a program in windows; not just that one regkey

Comment: Registry cleaners sometimes cause more problems than they fix.

Comment: Autoruns>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: Right click on the Name header and select command line column, what does it show?

Comment: The command line column was blank.

Comment: @BillCasey, if the Command Line column is blank, make sure you have run the program as admin. I'm not sure why that would matter, but it likely will for processes run by the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded Microsoft's [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) based on the comments I received on the question. When I ran it I noticed two entries in yellow that had the text "File not found" under the Image Path column. I deleted those entries, relaunched the task manager, and the "Program" was gone.

It looks like a helper executable from FireEye was not properly uninstalled during my machine's setup process.